# I can't put my form on the right side of the screen :(

Tags: html, css

I need this form on the left side of the screen to put some text on the right the page looks [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANvMG.png) and I need to make it look
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtvxG.png) (with some text on the left you can put lorem ipsum if you want)
If you know some fixes to code fell free to comment!
I'm using translator to write this, sorry gramatic errors.
Thank you all!!

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Overpass:ital,wght@0,400;1,700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baloo+2:wght@600&display=swap');
body {
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
}


/* HEADER */

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4.5rem;
  line-height: 4.5rem;
  background-color: #111111;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5rem 0 rgb(17 17 17 / 70%);
  cursor: default;
  z-index: 10000;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 2rem;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0.75rem;
  padding: 0;
}

img.Logo1 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 5px;
  height: 55px;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

img.Logo2 {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px;
  height: 55px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

img.Logo2:hover {
  opacity: 100;
}

a.botoes_menu {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Baloo 2', cursive;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18;
  line-height: 1, 3;
  letter-spacing: -1, 5;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

a.botoes_menu:hover {
  color: #a480ff;
}


/* TITULO */

h2.Titulo {
  font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 110px;
  font-size: 36;
  line-height: 1, 3;
  letter-spacing: -1, 5;
}

hr.Degrade {
  margin-top: -13px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 14rem;
  height: 4px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #a480ff, #532eaf);
}


/* RESTO */


/*nome e email*/

input.caixa {
  color: white;
  width: 18%;
  height: 36px;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: none;
  border: solid 1.5px #EBEBEB;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
}


/*mensagem*/

textarea {
  padding-top: 7px;
  color: white;
  width: 37%;
  height: 235px;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: none;
  border: solid 1.5px #EBEBEB;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}


/*características gerais*/

textarea:focus,
input:focus,
select:focus {
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0;
  border: solid 2.5px #532eaf;
  outline: 0;
}

::placeholder {
  text-align: center;
  color: #cccc;
  font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
}


/*checkbox*/

.container {
  font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 17px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.container input {
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkmark {
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container:hover input~.checkmark {
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.container input:checked~.checkmark {
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  background-color: #532eaf;
}

.checkmark:after {
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.container input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  display: block;
}

.container .checkmark:after {
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  top: 9px;
  left: 9px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
}


/*enviar*/

input.botão {
  margin-top: 17px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  background-color: #532eaf;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

input.botão:hover {
  color: #ccc;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  background-color: #2a0e70;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Contato - xCUELHO</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style_Contato.css">
</head>

<body>
  <! HEADER !>

  <header class="header">
    <a class="logo" href="index.html">
      <center>
        <div class="CaixaLogo">
          <img class="Logo1" src="Logo.png">
          <img class="Logo2" src="Logo2.png">
        </div>
      </center>
    </a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="botoes_menu" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="botoes_menu" href="Preços.html">Preços</a></li>
        <li><a class="botoes_menu" href="Contato.html">Contato</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <! TITULO !>

  <center>
    <h2 class="Titulo">Contato</h2>
    <hr class="Degrade">
  </center>
  <! RESTO !>
  <form method="post" action="Resultados.php">
    <input class="caixa" type="text" name="Nome" placeholder="Nome">
    <input class="caixa" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
    <textarea style="resize: vertical;" placeholder="Mensagem" name="area"></textarea><br>
    <label class="container">
      Compra
      <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
     </label>
    <label class="container">
      Outro
      <input type="radio" name="radio">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
     </label>
    <br/>
    <input class="botão" type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In your code snippet the form is already in the left side. What's the issue you are trying to address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `text-align: right;` on the form

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Overpass:ital,wght@0,400;1,700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baloo+2:wght@600&display=swap');
body {
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
}


/* HEADER */

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4.5rem;
  line-height: 4.5rem;
  background-color: #111111;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5rem 0 rgb(17 17 17 / 70%);
  cursor: default;
  z-index: 10000;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 2rem;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0.75rem;
  padding: 0;
}

img.Logo1 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 5px;
  height: 55px;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

img.Logo2 {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px;
  height: 55px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

img.Logo2:hover {
  opacity: 100;
}

a.botoes_menu {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Baloo 2', cursive;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18;
  line-height: 1, 3;
  letter-spacing: -1, 5;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

a.botoes_menu:hover {
  color: #a480ff;
}


/* TITULO */

h2.Titulo {
  font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 110px;
  font-size: 36;
  line-height: 1, 3;
  letter-spacing: -1, 5;
}

hr.Degrade {
  margin-top: -13px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 14rem;
  height: 4px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #a480ff, #532eaf);
}


/* RESTO */


/*nome e email*/

input.caixa {
  color: white;
  width: 18%;
  height: 36px;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: none;
  border: solid 1.5px #EBEBEB;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
}


/*mensagem*/

textarea {
  padding-top: 7px;
  color: white;
  width: 37%;
  height: 235px;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: none;
  border: solid 1.5px #EBEBEB;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}


/*características gerais*/

textarea:focus,
input:focus,
select:focus {
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0;
  border: solid 2.5px #532eaf;
  outline: 0;
}

::placeholder {
  text-align: center;
  color: #cccc;
  font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
}


/*checkbox*/

.container {
  font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 17px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.container input {
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkmark {
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container:hover input~.checkmark {
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.container input:checked~.checkmark {
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  background-color: #532eaf;
}

.checkmark:after {
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.container input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  display: block;
}

.container .checkmark:after {
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  top: 9px;
  left: 9px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
}


/*enviar*/

input.botão {
  margin-top: 17px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  background-color: #532eaf;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

input.botão:hover {
  color: #ccc;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  background-color: #2a0e70;
}

form {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Contato - xCUELHO</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style_Contato.css">
</head>

<body>
  <! HEADER !>

  <header class="header">
    <a class="logo" href="index.html">
      <center>
        <div class="CaixaLogo">
          <img class="Logo1" src="Logo.png">
          <img class="Logo2" src="Logo2.png">
        </div>
      </center>
    </a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="botoes_menu" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="botoes_menu" href="Preços.html">Preços</a></li>
        <li><a class="botoes_menu" href="Contato.html">Contato</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <! TITULO !>

  <center>
    <h2 class="Titulo">Contato</h2>
    <hr class="Degrade">
  </center>
  <! RESTO !>
  <form method="post" action="Resultados.php">

    <input class="caixa" type="text" name="Nome" placeholder="Nome">
    <input class="caixa" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
    <textarea style="resize: vertical;" placeholder="Mensagem" name="area"></textarea><br>
    <label class="container">Compra
                <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
    <label class="container">Outro
                <input type="radio" name="radio">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
    <br>
    <input class="botão" type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The intended use of `text-align` is to play with alignment of the text as the name suggests and shouldn't be used to move elements across. Properties such as `float`, `position` etc are available for that purpose.

Comment: @ZamAbdulVahid `text-align` is intended to align `inline` level Elements not just text, It's use here is pretty much fine.